# Rails: Store GPS coordinates with new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gps

I am trying to get browser GPS coordinates (on mobile device with GPS) in my rails app and save them in time of creation of new record. Is it possible and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use html5 geolocation, take a look at this example http://html5demos.com/geo.

Or you can get the request ip, and geolocate it by some service, but this method is not very accurate.

Take a look at this great gem called `geocoder` http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Comment: html5 way is awsome! thanks :) And geocoder gem is good too, but location of mobile device through IP address while on cellular is a bit tricky.